# Re-enable previews when using alt-tab in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I installed classic shell a few days ago and uninstalled it. Now a leftover problem is that the task switcher (alt + tab) only shows app icons (probably XP style?). I tried to find out how to switch back to default look but couldn't find where to configure it anywhere.  Where can I configure this?

Comment: It may be easiest to simply drop back to an older snapshot of the operating system by utilizing a [System Restore of Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html) just prior to when you installed the classic shell application.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that enabled. Hopefully someone knows a fix to this.

Comment: Really?  That is unfortunate.  Unless your hard drive is *extremely* low on free disk space, it is a "best practice" to have that enabled and configured.  There isn't another compelling reason to **not** utilize it.

Comment: yes, I disable it on purpose since I only have a 128GB SSD.

Comment: Honestly, in your situation I would *still* have it configured so that I had at least one System Restore point readily available.  I can almost guarantee you that this won't be the last time you encounter an issue that could have been solved very easily if it wasn't disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method using the Registry Editor that can do this. I do not recommend registry editing but it appears that it can be done.

Here are the main steps you may need for this operation:

> **How to enable old 'Alt + Tab' shortcut using Registry**
>
> To enable the legacy Alt + Tab shortcut style on Windows 10, use these
>   steps:
>
> **Warning**: This is a friendly reminder that editing the Registry is
>   risky, and it can cause irreversible damage to your installation if
>   you don't do it correctly. We recommend making a full backup of your
>   PC before proceeding.
>
> 1. Open **Start**.
> 2. Search for **regedit** and click the top result to open the **Registry**.
> 3. Browse the following path:
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
>    ```
>
> **Quick tip**: On Windows 10, you can now copy and paste the path in the
>   Registry's address bar to quickly jump to the key destination.
>
> 4. Right-click the **Explorer** (folder) key, select **New**, and click on **DWORD (32-bit) Value**.
> 5. Name the key **AltTabSettings** and press **Enter**.
> 6. Double-click the newly created DWORD and set the value from **0** to **1**.
> 7. Click the **OK** button.
> 8. Restart your computer.
>
> Once you complete these steps, you can use the Alt + Tab keyboard
>   shortcut to switch between running applications using the legacy
>   interface.
>
> If you want the modern task switcher back, you can always revert the changes by using the same instructions, but on **step No. 8**, change the DWORD value from **1** to **0**, or delete the **AltTabSettings** key, and restart your computer.

(Source: [How to bring back the old 'Alt + Tab' experience on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-bring-back-old-alt-tab-experience-windows-10))

Comment: actually I just found the same page a minute ago. Tried the registry fix in there, and it totally worked. thanks.